# To show that T is one one iff T' is one one

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Question is to show that T is one one iff T' is one one,where $T:V\to W $and $T':W'\to V'$.
I prove one way.
Say $T'g_{1}=T'g_{2}$ gives $(g_{1}-g_{2})T=0$ and since T is one one ,it can't be 0 so $g_{1}=g_{2}$.
I got confused while dealing other part.
Say $T\alpha_{1}=T\alpha_{2}$ gives $(T'g)(\alpha_{1}-\alpha_{2})$=0 ,where g is linear functional in W'.But from this step how can I conclude that $\alpha_{1}=\alpha_{2}$.

Comment: In the first part, how does $T$ being one-to-one (and thus non-zero) prevent $\operatorname{im}T$ from being a subset of $\ker(g_1-g_2)$?

Comment: We will get $(g1-g2)(v)=0$ which implies $g1=g2$,where v is in W.Am I wrong?

Comment: What is $V'$ ?..

Comment: Dual space of V